# How to make multiple assignment with prameter substitution in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to bash. There are two variables `al` and `tc`,
In `al` I want to store `/home/matrix/var_0_limit`
In `tc` I want to store `/home/matrix/var_1_limit`
so I tried doing it like following

```
read al tc <<< $(cat /home/matrix/var_{0,1}_limit)
```

but when running the above statement, only al is assigned.
Can you tell me what I am missing here and why it doesn't work? Could you tell me how to assign these values in a single line?

Comment: `In al I want to store /home/matrix/var_0_limit` Do you want to store the _content_ of the file in `al` or the filename in `al`? Just `al=/home/matrix/var_0_limit`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I want to store the content of the files in the variables.

Comment: so what is wrong with a good old `al=$(cat /home/matrix/var_0_limit)` and `tc=$(cat /home/matrix/var_1_limit)`? `in a single line?` Why is a single line a requirement? Is it important it's a single line? What for?

Comment: @KamilCuk There is no problem, it just has a long path.. and I thought if there was a better way of doing it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> want to assign them in one line because they have long paths

Then they have *long paths*, so abstract *the path*, not the assignment.

```
gen_path() {
    echo "/home/matrix/var_${1}_limit"
}
al=$(cat "$(gen_path 0)")
tc=$(cat "$(gen_path 1)")
# or shorter in bash
al=$(<"$(gen_path 0)")
tc=$(<"$(gen_path 1)")
```

Answer (score 0):

To populate several variables, the values must be on the same line. Use `tr` to remove the newline between the values.

```
read al tc <<< $(cat /home/matrix/var_{0,1}_limit | tr '\n' ' ')
```

You can also use a normal redirection instead of the here-word:

```
read al tc < <(cat /home/matrix/var_{0,1}_limit | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Or, read each line into each variable using a block to group the reads:

```
{ read al ; read tc ; } < <(cat /home/matrix/var_{0,1}_limit)
```

But, why is any of it better than

```
read al < /home/matrix/var_0_limit
read tc < /home/matrix/var_1_limit
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but all the three solutions you have suggested are setting the value of both the variables to `0`. I should mention that when I check the type with `file var_0_limit` it says `var_0_limit: ASCII text` might that be of importance.. And I want to assign them in one line because they have long paths..